# SPO 2013 Editing embeded html markup in a client editor

Tags: 2013, content-editor-web-part, html, html-editor

I don't like SharePoint Designer - especially 2013.

Editing embedded HTML in SPO 2013 pages using the SPO UI is ridiculous in that little window and with the 4 clicks to get to the source code.

If I open the page with my editor I don't see the embedded code??

Any way to edit the embedded code from my client NotePad++ or editor of choice?

Any way to reference another HTML files we can edit from embed code?

Blue sky .. but anybody else want MS to invest in a better built in Code Editor in SPO?  How about something that lets you WYSIWYG Drag and Drop Design Pages on SPO and bind to available fields so we can build much better List Views???  I'm hoping FOSL goes this way kinda with what they did with Access 2013 on SPO.